# How to prevent overflow with flex into a pseudo element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, pseudo-element

I have a list where I use 5 divs with `flex-basis` to space the content in every li row. Each of these divs have a `data-label` attribute with a title for alternate view for mobile devices. So I have a media query which looks like this:

```
.col {
  content: attr(data-label);
  flex-basis: 107px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

With above setup I get the folowing result which I do not really know the terminology of. In the screenshot I observe the bottom 3 cols to have transitioned correctly and neatly alligned. But the top one for some reason *¿Overflows?* into the area of the `:before`

[image]

Does anyone know the correct terminology of this behaviour or have any tips on how to prevent this from happening so that they all allign neatly? I have tried ALOT of things fiddling in the element inspect to see what has effect and whatnot but I just can not figure it out.

[Jsfiddle reproducing the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/x47a81yo/)

Comment: Could you pop your HTML on too so we can recreate this issue?

Comment: You need to provide a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: Jep sorry long time since using stackoverflow, theres a JSfiddle which reproduces the problem.

Comment: You can create [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) which is preferrable over JSFiddle because it keeps all the code on this page and avoids the risk of having a dead link in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex children have a `flex-shrink: 1` set by the browser. If you want to prevent a flex child from getting smaller than the set `flex-basis`, then be sure to disable the shrink property to `0`.

```
.cart-col::before {
  flex-shrink: 0;

  content: attr(data-label);
  flex-basis: 107px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Aah oke, I didnt know that thanks for the tags and explanation, I will continue to read up on this. This also solves my problem in one go.